# Radviz python not showing points?

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to draw radviz of my data-frame. This data didn't have class attribute, so I created a temporary attribute 'active' with all values 1. But when I am trying to plot the radviz, it's not showing any points in the figure. I used the below code:

```
from pandas.plotting import radviz
plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))
radviz(result_data,'active')
```

[image]

Comment: The data must be in some kind of numerical type. Is that the case ?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to remove columns that are full of zero:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[(table==0).all(axis=0)], axis=1)
```